# On x86 if [mem] is not 32-bit aligned, can "lock inc [mem]" still work fine?

Tags: multithreading, assembly, x86, multiprocessing

On x86, if mem is 32-bit aligned, the mov operation is guaranteed to be atomic.

if [mem] is not 32-bit aligned, can `lock inc [mem]` sill work fine?

work fine:provide atomicity and not get partial value.

Comment: By "work fine" you mean does it provide atomicity? Or just whether it increments?

Comment: work fine:provide atomicity and not get partial value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Intel Instruction Set Reference](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html/) for x86 and x64 mentions nothing about alignment requirements for the INC instruction. All it says in reference to `LOCK` is:

> This instruction can be used with a LOCK prefix
>   to allow the instruction to be  executed atomically.

The `LOCK` prefix documentation states:

> The integrity of the LOCK prefix is not affected by the alignment of the memory field. 
>   Memory locking is observed for arbitrarily misaligned fields.

Comment: I also see nothing about alignment requirements for the MOV instruction. But MOV is affected by misalignment.

Comment: How is `MOV` affected by misalignment? It successfully reads/writes the data regardless of alginment.

Comment: A very precise answer. However, like @Vince mentioned, `mov` is also guaranteed to work for unaligned address, but there's a penalty. I suspect that using `lock` semantics on an unaligned address is something similar, with potentially even greater complications.

Comment: The OP asked if the instructions would "work fine." And that they do.

Comment: see Volume3 8.1.1 in Software Developer's Manunal:Reading or writing a doubleword aligned on a 32-bit boundary

Comment: read "How to solve bugs of simultaneously misaligned memory accesses":http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=75386   it show the real work issue about MOV

Comment: "Unaligned 16-, 32-, and 64-bit accesses to cached memory that fit within a cache line" will always be carried out atomically. But, at the same time, it says "however, nonaligned data accesses will 
seriously impact the performance of the processor and should be avoided."   --- So, I'm definitely not disagreeing with anyone that the unaligned operations should be avoided. I'm just stating that the instructions *will* execute as intended.

Comment: your said line is about cache line. I'm saying the line above line:Reading or writing a doubleword aligned on a 32-bit boundary will always be carried out atomically. it indicates accessing to a doubleword not aligned on 32-bit boundary will not be.

Comment: If the address of a doubleword (32-bit operand) is not aligned at a 32-bit boundary then it *might* not be done atomically, it depends on whether it crosses a cache line boundary or not.  If it is aligned then the manual says categorically that it will be atomic.  Note that some 128-bit moves to/from memory *must* be aligned or you get a fault... their mnemonic indicates that: for example MOVDQA is an SSE load/store (MOV) of a double quadword (DQ) whose address must be aligned (A), thus the name MOVDQA.

Answer (score 2):

The lock prefix will provide atomicity for unaligned memory access.  On QPI systems this could be very slow.  See this post on Intel website:

How to solve bugs of simultaneously misaligned memory accesses

http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=75386

Comment: good answer. please help answer other question from "Jonathon Reinhart".

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, or what we're arguing about. I think we all agree that a) the instructions will work correctly regardless of alignment. b) unaligned accesses should be avoided for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

While the hardware might be fine with unaligned accesses, the code implementation might be relying on stealing the low 2 or 3 bits of the pointer (always zero for 32 or 64 bit aligned pointers respectively).

For example, the (Win32) InterlockedPushSList function doesn't store the low 2 or 3 bits of the pointer, so any attempt to push or pop an unaligned object will not work as intended. It is common for lock-free code to cram extra information into a pointer sized object. Most of the time this is not an issue though.

Intel's processors have always had excellent misaligned access performance. On the Nehalem (Core I7), they went all the way: any misaligned access fully within a cache line has no penalty, and misaligned accesses that cross a cache line boundary have an average 4.5-cycle penalty - very small.